# NSUserDefaultsController keys return nil

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I'm trying to implement a preference panel. I have an NSTextField that is bound to the `Shared User Defaults Controller`. The controller key is `values` and the Model Key Path is `FolderPath`.

Every time I try to access that value in code, the string is nil:

```
NSString *s = [[[NSUserDefaultsController sharedUserDefaultsController] defaults] stringForKey:@"FolderPath"];
NSLog(s);
```

If I set a default dictionary, the value in the text box displays it properly, but it is still nil when retrieving it again.

```
    NSDictionary *appDefaults = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"foo"
                                                            forKey:@"FolderPath"];
    [[NSUserDefaultsController sharedUserDefaultsController] setInitialValues:appDefaults];
```

Am I missing something basic here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you ever send this user defaults controller a `-save:` message? If not, the values you set probably aren't being saved.

Comment: Yup, that did it. I must've missed that bit in the various tutorials.